# Django Migrations Says Database Backend Isn't Available

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, django-migrations

I'm trying to upgrade a Django 1.6.2 application to 1.7.10.  I'm running PostgreSQL on my Mac using the [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) version 9.3.4 that runs PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and PostGIS 2.1.1.  The problem I'm having is that when I run the new "makemigrations" command, I'm getting the following error (the entire stacktrace is at the bottom):

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseSpatialOperations
```

Here are the pertinent settings:

```
# conf/settings/base.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME'    : 'geodb',
        'USER'    : 'geo',
        'PASSWORD': 'geopassword',   # not really
        'HOST'    : 'localhost',
        'PORT'    : '',
    }
}
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'apps.admin',  # my apps live in an apps subdir.
    'apps.home',
)
POSTGIS_VERSION = (2,1,1)
```

I used this same DATABASE ENGINE setting in my Django 1.6.2 application without any problems.  In researching this, some other developers forgot to install psycopg2 in their virtual environment but I do have version 2.6.1 installed in mine.  I was using version 2.5.2 with Django 1.6.2 but if I roll psycopg2 back to that version I still get this error.  I've read all the psycopg2 release notes between those two versions and didn't see anything that might cause this problem.
The Django 1.7 [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#configure-settings-py) also uses this postgis engine setting so it doesn't appear to be deprecated and there isn't anything pertinent in the Django 1.7 release notes that indicate this could be a problem.

I also built a test version of the GeoDjango tutorial mentioned above and if I run the makemigrations command on it, I get the very same error.

Finally, I've done a web search and don't see any articles that discuss this migrations/database engine problem.  Does anyone see what's wrong?

Thanks!

```
# Full stacktrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/me/venv/dj_17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseSpatialOperations
```

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest postgres.app, which comes with PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and PostGIS 2.1.7 (remember to update your `POSTGIS_VERSION` setting as well. It might be worth re-installing psycopg2 as well.

Comment: First of all why are you upgrading to the now almost end of life 1.7 version instead of the LTS 1.8 version? you will need to go through all this again in December. Secondly have you followed this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/  thirdly are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @e4c5 I am going to up 1.8 but I think it's better to make a stop iat 1.7, go through the release notes and bring things up-to-date for that version, and then proceed to 1.8 rather than go straight from 1.6 to 1.8.  As for the geolibs, they all come installed in the Postgres app.  And yes, I do use a virtual environment.

Comment: @Alasdair I followed your advice but that didn't fix the problem.  I updated PostgreSQL/PostGIS, updated the POSTGIS setting, and re-installed psycop2 but no luck.

Comment: I wish you all the best, whatever effort that you are putting in now will have to be repeated (and probably in bigger dosage) in december. If you are using virtualenvs please check that the new and the old virtualenvs are the same (except for django version)

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid, hope you figure it out. Upgrading to 1.8 via 1.7 sounds sensible.

Comment: @Alasdair actually I upgraded to 1.8.4 out of desperation last night and it actually solved the problem but I'm not sure why.  Now I have another problem to try and figure out but at least I'm past this one.  Thanks for checking back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of ideas, I upgraded Django from 1.7.10 to 1.8.4 and the problem went away.  I don't know why this fixed it but it did.

Comment: This problem actually rears its ugly head again in Django 1.10. Downgrading to 1.9 fixed my issue.

Comment: Same problem as @davetw12 - downgrading to the latest 1.9 resolved it

Comment: Check out my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574472/django-migrations-says-database-backend-isnt-available/39395522#answer-39395522) for upgrading to 1.10

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar problems upgrading from 1.9.9 to 1.10.1

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
```

It went away by upgrading the `gdal` dependency -> `brew install --upgrade gdal` for me on OSX

Answer (score 1):

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg' is not an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
  'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Well i did exactly what was told,changed the engine to:

```
"ENGINE":"django.db.backends.postgresql"
```

it works now.

(before this i tried `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin` which didn't work -> so if above solution doesn't work, you should do this too.)

Answer (score 0):

Proper fix is to install `gdal-bin` package (`sudo apt-get install gdal-bin`). For Xenial (16.04), it's already available in standard packages. For earlier versions, you might need to do these two additional steps before doing `apt-get install`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```