# Issue with Connecting Django to Postgresql database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

When I try to connect my app to postgresql db I always get this same error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

Here is my code in settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

I am using django version 3.0.2 and my psycopg2 version 2.8.5 . I did downgrade to earlier version of django and still the problem persists. Also my python version is 3.8.
I tried doing this too

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

I thought it was the issue with the virtual env so I decided to perform on other projects too but still does not work. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574472/django-migrations-says-database-backend-isnt-available

Comment: are you sure you have installed psycopg2 in same virtualenv and it didnt fail to install show us pip freeze result from your environment

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling the psycopg2. I installed psycopg2-binary.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```