# I am facing a error about Django related to make migration ...how can I fix it? the version of installed Django is 3.1.5

Tags: django, pycharm

File "C:\Users\Yogiraj Patil\PycharmProjects\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 122, in load_backend

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgreysql' isn't an available database backend.

Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Comment: Did you look at [Django Migrations Says Database Backend Isn't Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574472/django-migrations-says-database-backend-isnt-available)?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t you have a typo with ‘postgreysql’?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you didn't configure your database correct. For the next time it would be very helpful if could provide your settings.py so we can take a look at your configuration.

Your error says that

```
'django.db.backends.postgreysql' isn't an available database backend
```

Maybe it is enough to change postgreysql to postgresql (there is a typo).
So it can find the appropriate backend.

Make sure your settings.py is configured correct to connect to your installation of a postgresql database.